# Before asking for permissions Android application closed ? How resolve that?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

The first time I install this application, and when I launch MapsActivity, I am asked for permissions, which is normal. But the problem is that the application closes in the meantime. How can I modify my code to keep the application open, and the permission pop-up just overlaps. Thank you very much for your answer.

Error code in logcat :

```
2020-02-02 11:17:01.340 11559-11574/? E/le.rsr_pechhlu: Unable to peek into adb socket due to error. Closing socket.: Connection reset by peer
```

2020-02-02 11:17:01.470 11559-11636/? E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@2f88384
2020-02-02 11:17:01.470 11559-11636/? E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@7fa676d
2020-02-02 11:17:01.471 11559-11603/? E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2020-02-02 11:17:10.787 11559-11559/com.example.rsr_pechhlup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rsr_pechhlup, PID: 11559
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.rsr_pechhlup/com.example.rsr_pechhlup.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4742)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4691)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4626)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:45)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.removeUpdates(android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rsr_pechhlup.MapsActivity.onPause(MapsActivity.java:159)
        at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7663)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1536)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4691) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4626) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:45) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap googleMap; //google map is contained in the fragment work on it to change the position of the map and so on.
private Marker marker;
private Button buttonCallNow;
private RelativeLayout callPanelWrapper;
private static final int PERMS_CALL_ID = 1234; //permission identifier, unique identifier
private static final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 4321;
private LocationManager locationManager; // Android manager service of android platform.
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private Utils utils;
private PhoneCallListener phoneCallListener;
private boolean firstTime;
private String adresse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
     mapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
}

/**
 * //When the activity comes back to the foreground, I have to subscribe to the different location information providers, so I will receive the new location information and I will be able to resynchronize my mapping on this location.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPermissions();
    firstTime=true;
}

private void checkPermissions(){
    //For older versions of android we check that the ACCES_FINE_LOCATION and ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION permissions are enabled.
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,  Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },PERMS_CALL_ID); //We must provide three parameters: it is the activity that requires the activation of these permissions (here it is this), then a table that specifies the set of permissions to allow. And we need a request code.
        return;
    }

    locationManager= (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//I ask android to give me that service locationManager. LOCATION SERVICE comes inheritance FragmentActivity, which inherits from Context, which contains this constant.

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){//If on this locationManager, a particular provider here : LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER is allowed. If I have a GPS type sensor that is enabled, on the locationManager I will be able to subscribe to events.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);//This function requires the type of provider: LocationManager.GPS.it needs the frequency in milliseconds at which I want new location information(Here all the seconds).It needs to notify a person, who is going to receive this notification information, it's the MapsActivity, so this.
    }

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)){//If on this locationManager, a particular provider here : LocationManager.PASIVE_PROVIDER is allowed. If I have a GPS type sensor that is enabled, on the locationManager I will be able to subscribe to events.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);//This function requires the type of provider: LocationManager.GPS.it needs the frequency in milliseconds at which I want new location information(Here all the seconds).It needs to notify a person, who is going to receive this notification information, it's the MapsActivity, so this.
    }

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){//If on this locationManager, a particular provider here : NETWORK is allowed. If I have a GPS type sensor that is enabled, on the locationManager I will be able to subscribe to events.
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,1000,0,this);//This function requires the type of provider: LocationManager.GPS.it needs the frequency in milliseconds at which I want new location information(Here all the seconds).It needs to notify a person, who is going to receive this notification information, it's the MapsActivity, so this.
    }

    dispMap();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==PERMS_CALL_ID){ //This method will be activated each time a permission request is made. And to know where I'm coming from I need the requestCode. This request is coupled with this requestCode here.
        checkPermissions(); //i call again chack permission do disp again pop-up permission.
    }
}

/**
 * //When my application leaves the foreground, I unsubscribe from the different providers of location information so as not to consume a lot of resources.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //If the locationManager has been initialized, I make one of this, one of the earphone of all suppliers
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

private void dispMap(){
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            MapsActivity.this.googleMap=googleMap;

            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(43.799345,6.725426)));

        }
    });
}



/**
 * React each time new positioning information is calculated
 * @param location
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { //This location is obtained through the provider. Of course this can be any provider, GPS_PROVIDER is more accurate than PASSIVE_PROVIDER etc..
    double latitude= location.getLatitude();//I'm getting the latitude.
    double longitude=location.getLongitude();// I'm getting the longitude.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location: " + latitude + "/" + longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LatLng googleLocation=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    if(firstTime){
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(googleLocation, 16.2f));
        adresse= Utils.getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude,this);
        BitmapDescriptor subwayBitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker);
        marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(googleLocation).icon(subwayBitmapDescriptor).title(adresse));
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(this));

    }
    firstTime=false;

    if(this.googleMap!=null){//If my map is correctly displayed
        adresse = Utils.getCompleteAddressString(latitude, longitude,this);
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(this));
        marker.setTitle(adresse);
        marker.setPosition(googleLocation);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
    }
}

/**
 * To react to every change of state
 * @param provider
 * @param status
 * @param extras
 */
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

/**
 * When a location provider is closed.
 * @param provider
 */
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

/**
 * When a location provider is closed.
 * @param provider
 */
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}



public void btnBackClick(View view) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

public void btnCallMapclicked(View view) {
    callPanelWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    buttonCallNow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

public void buttonFinalCallClicked(View view) {
    call();
}

public void popupClosedClicked(View view) {
    callPanelWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    buttonCallNow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

}
```

}

Comment: Your error code in logcat can guide you for solving this issue.Could you send us the error logged in logcat(logcat with filter of 'fatal exception')

Comment: I add it on my post thak you for answer .

Comment: If after passing permission your app is closed I think either  you forgot to add an activity to your manifest or one of your source xml files is destroyed.Remember the first time that to got this exception.. and before it , you were working on which activity or layout , then refer to that xml and with commenting of various parts try to running without any exception.After that work on the target part causes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to put comment,Thus forward my answer as post.

you may should describe about your problem more but do you add `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and

`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` to your Manifest file?

**EDIT:** 
just change `onPause` to following:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();


      if(locationManager != null) // add this line to your code
         locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

**Cause:**
When Permission dialog has been shown your activity `onPause()` is called, and since you not initialize location manager yet, it throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I have the both permissions on my manifest. The request for permission is made except that the application closes. Once you accept permission, everything works perfectly... But I don't want the application to close when I ask for permission I want to be able to accept this request without the application closing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to initialize map with required run time permission.

```
 public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
        getDeviceLocation();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        init();
    }
}

private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;


//vars
private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


    getLocationPermission();

}


private void initMap(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            initMap();
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
    mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                    if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                        return;
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;

                initMap();  // once permission granted then only initMap()
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```